# Command spell cast twice (PF2e)

Tags: spells, pathfinder-2e, stacking

Inspired by this [question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/180671/command-spell-cast-twice-before-someones-turn-happen), and by the fact that it *almost* happened in a recent session.

What happens if a target fails against two *different* [Command](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=45) spells that give different commands (say, approach and run away)? Since fail specifies the first action, it's quite ambiguous. I was ready to house rule it stacked (i.e. first action is first command, second action is second command), but that was just a ruling to keep the session going.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### The higher level or the most recent *command* applies.

The rules for [Duplicate Effects](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=312) state:

> When you’re affected by the same thing multiple times, only one instance applies, using the higher level of the effects, or the newer effect if the two are the same level. For example, if you were using mage armor and then cast it again, you’d still benefit from only one casting of that spell. Casting a spell again on the same target might get you a better duration or effect if it were cast at a higher level the second time, but otherwise doing so gives you no advantage.

So the higher level casting applies, or the most recent, if they were the same level.